# Wrong serpentine belt

Tags: chevrolet, belt, caprice

I have a 93 Chevy Caprice Classic 5.0
I had the serpentine belt replaced but he used a belt that was the wrong belt - 2 inches longer.  A 950 instead of the 930.

Since then I have had the alternator go out and the belt tension assemnbly bracket break.

It has been repaired with the correct belt.  Did thew wrong belt contribute to my problems?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! That's going to be really hard to tell. It may have had an impact, but it really depends on what happened to the different parts.